# Understanding C++ Template Error

Tags: c++, templates, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
    return  a < b  ?  b : a;
}

inline char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)
{ 
    return  std::strcmp(a,b) < 0  ?  b : a;
}

template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    return max (max(a,b), c);  // error
}

int main ()
{
    ::max(7, 42, 68);     // OK

    const char* s1 = "frederic";
    const char* s2 = "anica";
    const char* s3 = "lucas";
    ::max(s1, s2, s3);    // ERROR

}
```

Could anybody please tell me why this is an error?

Comment: Please post the actual error you're seeing, not just "ERROR"?

Comment: ...especially when the program is well-formed and should compile.

Comment: By the way, templates are `inline` by default, so on the 1st and 3rd function you can remove the keyword.

Comment: @GMan: No, template functions and template member functions follow the same linkage rules as non-template functions. If you put a function template into a header (declaration + definition) and then #include that definition in multiple translation units, you get the same pain as with non-template functions.

Comment: @GMan and #phresnel - I'm afraid you're both wrong. You don't need inline in front of your templates: they will link just fine. But at the same time, you DO have to annotate them as inline if you want to hint at the compiler that they should be optimized.

Comment: @phresnel: Nope, templates are inline by default, sorry. I'd find it in the standard but I need to leave. Try out your own example, you'll see. @Manuel: That use for the `inline` keyword died a long time ago. Compilers do whatever they want, and certainly don't care if you have a little ol' keyword in front of a function.

Comment: @GMan, the standard does differentiate between inline function template and non-inline function template. However, even non-inline templates are allowed to be defined in multiple translation units, so there is absolutely no difference whatsoever between these types of function templates as far as the standard is concerned. And as you correctly pointed out, for quite a long time now, compilers don't differentiate between them either.

Comment: @GMan - Yes, that's why I said "hint".

Comment: @avakar, Manuel: I think you are right, and I also feel that I was the one that pointed to GMan that template functions are inlined by default in another question. My bad. Anyway, while they are not inlined, the behavior will be the same.

Comment: @GMan: "Templates are inline" is incomplete in itself; can classes be inline? Then, 14.7.3, Explicit Specialization: "[...] An explicit specialization of a function template is inline only if it is explicitly declared to be, and independently of whether its function template is.".  See also: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/compiler/ref/tutmplat3.htm .

Q: How will you mark a function template non-inline?

// edit: need to press refresh more often, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say:

```
 max (max(a,b), c)
```

`max(char*,char*)` returns a pointer BY VALUE. You then return a reference to this value. To make this work, you should make all your max() functions return values rather than references, as I think was suggested in an answer to your previous question, or make the char* overload take and return references to pointers.

Comment: @Neil: Wouldn't it be better to have string version use `const&` in the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a reference to a temporary. The `char*` overload of max returns by value, but the 3-arg template returns by reference.

I don't know exactly why you get an error. I only get a warning on my compiler (GCC). I imagine if you posted the error text, though, someone could figure it out.

Comment: @Steve: Maybe warnings as errors, I only get a warning too in MSVC++.

Comment: @GMan, yes, for instance in GCC with -Werror, the message "warnings being treated as errors" would be a clue ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to return a reference, then you have to modify the second overload to return a reference too.

```
char const* const & max (char const* const & a, char const* const & b)
```

Comment: A typedef helps here too: `typedef const char* cstring; inline const cstring& max(const cstring& a, const cstring& b)`

Answer (score 1):

Your example is equivalent to this, maybe you'll see it better this way:

```
int foo()
{
    return 0;
}

int const & bar()
{
    return foo(); // Reference to what???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When compiling, I get:

```
maxtest.cpp: In function `const T& max(const T&, const T&, const T&) [with T = const char*]':
maxtest.cpp:29:   instantiated from here
maxtest.cpp:19: warning: returning reference to temporary
```

That would be because you're returning a reference to a temporary (i.e. your object no longer exists by the time the caller of the function can check its value).  This is certainly *a* bug but, since you said *error*, I suspect it isn't the bug you meant.

Some of the headers in Visual Studio #define min and max.  To get around that, put parentheses around min and max:

```
return (max) ( (max) (a, b), c );
```

Answer (score 0):

gcc 4.2.1 gives a warning about returning reference to a temporary, so, changing your code to return by value helps.

BTW: I also renamed `max` to `my_max`, since [`max`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) is already defined in `<algorithm>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
inline T const my_max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
    return  a < b  ?  b : a;
}

inline char const* my_max (char const* a, char const* b)
{
    return  std::strcmp(a,b) < 0  ?  b : a;
}

template <typename T>
inline T const my_max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    return my_max (my_max(a,b), c);  // error
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << my_max(7, 42, 68) << "\n"; // OK

    const char* s1 = "frederic";
    const char* s2 = "anica";
    const char* s3 = "lucas";
    std::cout << my_max(s1, s2, s3) << "\n"; // NO ERROR

}
```

`gcc -Wall -Wextra file.cpp -o test` gives no warnings or errors, output is:

> 68
>   lucas